# Change output of only the first line in bash script

Tags: bash, unix, sed

Here is my source :

```
TABLE;APGFPOLI;
```

And here is the output that i want :

```
01 APGFPOLI.
```

So what i am trying to do is remove "TABLE" and add 01 before "**APGFPOLI**". I need to do it for the first line only. So i tried to do :

```
    #!/bin/bash

#Fichier Source
fichier="APGFPOLI.des.txt"

champAdd="05 "

if [[ -f "$fichier" ]]
then
    
    # read it
    sed -i '1 s/TABLE//' $fichier |sed -i 's/CHAR/PIC X/' $fichier | sed -E '/Numérique/s/;Numérique\s+([^;]*)/;PIC 9(\1)/' $fichier | while IFS=';' read -r nomChamp format libelle
    do
        echo \* $libelle
        echo $champAdd $nomChamp $format.
    done > test.txt
fi
```

As you can see, my first sed is supposed to remove TABLE but it dont work. i also do a echo for my others line but i'd like to echo this specific first line too.

Here is the output my bash gives me :

```
  *
05 TABLE APGFPOLI.
```

Here is my full source if it helps :

```
TABLE;APGFPOLI;
Contrat;CHAR(16);Numéro du contrat
Libelle;CHAR(30);Libellé du contrat
DtCreation;CHAR(8);Date de création
DtMaj;CHAR(8);Date de dernière MAJ
DtEffet;CHAR(8);Date d'effet adhésion
MotifAdh;CHAR(2);Motif d'adhésion
DtRadiation;CHAR(8);Date de radiation
DtEnrRad;CHAR(8);Date enregistrement radiat
MotifRad;CHAR(2);Motif de radiation
MtPrime;Numérique 8.2;Montant prime d'origine
DtEffetSusp;CHAR(8);Date d'effet de suspension
DtFinSusp;CHAR(8);Date de fin de suspension
MotifSusp;CHAR(2);Motif de suspension
DestBord;CHAR(1);Destinataire du bordereau
CdDest;CHAR(5);Code du destinataire
NivRupBord;CHAR(1);Niveau rupture bordereau
BordCETIP;CHAR(1);Bordereau CTIP
EnvBordNom;CHAR(1);Envoi bordereau nominatif
Indice;CHAR(2);Indice appliqué
Echeance;CHAR(2);Echéance de l'indice (MM)
Effectif;CHAR(5);Effectif
CdRegr;CHAR(3);Code regroupement 1
CdGroupe;CHAR(3);Code regroupement 2
Periodicite;CHAR(1);Périodicité
Terme;CHAR(1);Terme
Produit;CHAR(6);Code produit affecté
Inspecteur;CHAR(5);Inspecteur
CleInsp;CHAR(1);Clé inspecteur
Filler;CHAR(6);Filler
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to add the flag `-i` to the command `sed` and to give the name of a file as argument when you are reading the input from the standard input stream with the operator `|` in `bash`.

Comment: for the moment i do that for one file only but, i'll need to do it for a whole directory of files. that's why

Comment: @YoussefHammouma It doesn't matter whether you're operating on one file or many; `sed -i` doesn't make any sense in a pipeline. The point of a pipeline is to pass the output from one command to the input of another, but `sed -i` doesn't produce any output, or read any input. You need to either do the edit with a *single* `sed -i` command (no pipe, no `read`, no `echo`, etc), or make a shell loop over the files (something like `for fichier in *.des.txt; do ...`) and use `sed` *without* the `-i` (and only pass the file to the first `sed` command, so the others read from the pipe, not the file).

Comment: For `#!/bin/bash` to do anything useful, the characters `#` and `!` need to be literally the first two bytes of the file. The indentation you show in your question changes this line into just a comment and no longer a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally don't want to run `sed -i` on the same file more than once.

Your entire task can be rephrased into just

```
sed -i '1s/TABLE/01 /' APGFPOLI.des.txt
```

If the replacement string should come from a shell variable, you need to use double quotes instead of single:

```
replacement="05"
sed -i "1s/TABLE/$replacement /" APGFPOLI.des.txt
```

If you want to keep your other tasks (which are not documented in the question) you can easily merge them into the same script.  Remember, `sed`  is a scripting language; you can feed in arbitrarily complex scripts (and some crazy people have even implemented desk calculators and Game of Life in `sed` scripts).

```
sed -i -E -e '1 s/TABLE/01 /' -e 's/CHAR/PIC X/' \
          -e '/Numérique/s/;Numérique\s+([^;]*)/;PIC 9(\1)/' APGFPOLI.des.txt
```

If after this you want to pull out the result and display it with some decorations, I would add a second `sed` script without `-i` so that it displays the output on standard output without modifying the file.

```
sed '1s/\([^;]*\);\([^;]*\);\([^;]*\);.*/* \3\n05 \2 \1/;q'  APGFPOLI.des.txt
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much. But now with the "echoes" that i put in the shell i have this output : "05 01 APGFPOLI." . Is there a way to echo my first line without the "05" unlike all the other lines ?

Comment: I would just run another `sed` to pull out the first line and add the decorations you want around it to standard output. See updated answer with a rough sketch now (hope I transcribed your fields correctly).

Comment: I think that i did full bullsh*t. I saw that sed actually edit my source file. I do not want that, i want to keep my source like that and create a target file with the modifications i did. I am so lost, how can i do that i never tought that sed edit the source file :(

Comment: Remove the `-i` option if you don't want to write the changes back to the input file. Going forward, probably spend more time on explaining your _actual_ requirements.

Comment: Ok but why removing the -i option removed the changes in the output file ? Because i removed all the -i so i can keep my original source. But now when i cat my output file there is no changes on it

Comment: You said you did not want the source file to change, now you say you do. You can't want both. Probably ask a new question if this cannot be solved succinctly here in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

For removing `TABLE;` from the first line and to prepend `01` , you just have to do:

```
fichier="APGFPOLI.des.txt"
sed -i '1s/^TABLE;/01 /' "$fichier"
```

When you ask something in SO, it is advisable to remove the part of the code that is not relevant to your problem, like the command `sed -i 's/CHAR/PIC X/' $fichier` and so on.